# Cannot track lumen job dispatch twice

Tags: laravel, queue, lumen, jobs

I'm using Laravel lumen 8.x for creating REST API's.
In my project i have case where i'm calling third party API's for those API's i have created jobs for calling API's. in my Log i am getting Job Execution once but on that Third party API they are saying I'm calling one API multiple times.
I have tested this with a Single php File without any Framework. on that API call they said its fine because it was called one time.
I think something wrong with my Lumen project or in queue config. anyone can help ?
Running Command:

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=600 --sleep=5 --tries=1 --memory=1024
```

**Here is my queue.php config**

```
return [
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'redis'),
    'connections' => [
        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => null,
        ],
        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            // 'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'queue' =>'default',
            'retry_after' => null,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],
    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I could think of is that your job takes longer then expected, therefore it times out, and it gets retried again.
You might wanna checkout the timeout configuration for jobs in laravels docs

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#timeout

Also you can specify how many times the job might be attempted before failing, by default its 3 I guess

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout

Comment: php artisan queue:work --timeout=600 --sleep=5 --tries=1 --memory=1024

I'm already using timeout & retry limit to 1